# Base64 encode on number in javascript

Tags: javascript

I used this base64 and uriencode on a number

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/core-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script>
    var num= '1418265869452';
    var base64num =  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(salt)); 
    var encodeuri = encodeURIComponent(base64num);
</script>
```

base64 num gives me MTQxODI2NTg2OTQ1Mg==

But actually i also needs to uri encode it after base64 encode

when i tried to encodeURIComponent(base64num) it throwed me an error as follows:

```
 Exception thrown from JavaScript : Error: Malformed UTF-8 data
```

How to achieve this

Comment: Where do you set `salt`? And what is `num` used for?

Comment: I changed `salt` to `num` and it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/nbuapp07/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen encodeURIComponent  throw JS errors. Its probably someplace in the third party library. Depending on your [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=atob-btoa) requirements you might be able to use the built in base64 encoder/decoders

[image]

```
var base64num = btoa('1418265869452'),
    encodeuri = encodeURIComponent(base64num);
encodeuri; // "MTQxODI2NTg2OTQ1Mg%3D%3D"
```

***This could also be happening when you try to decode it. First you have to decodeURIComponent before trying to base64 decode it.***

Answer (score 0):

You are passing **salt variable** as a parameter, but I am not seeing any initialization of it. Instead you need to pass **num**, then it will start working, as I have used **num** in place of **salt** and is working perfectly fine at my end.

Here is the updated [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/doyvf2em/)

**Updated Code:**

```
var num= '1418265869452';
var base64num =  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(num)); 
var encodeuri = encodeURIComponent(base64num);
alert(encodeuri);
```